# Enable exec function

Tags: php, apache

I have a website on a shared server (apache), one of my scripts needs the exec function to work, but my web host seems to have disabled it..is there any way to enable it through .htaccess?

Comment: What error message are you getting (if any)?

Comment: What is it your script does?  Maybe there's another way to do it without exec

Comment: I'm trying to backup my site's MySQL databases through a backup script provided by [Backup Machine](http://www.backupmachine.com/) which is executed directly from my website since MySQl Remote Connections are also disableb by my host and I don't have SSH access either

Answer (score 4):

No. `disable_functions` directive is only available in `php.ini` for security reasons. See [the documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), column "**Changeable**".

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. That is a php internal setting, whilst .htaccess only deals with apache internal request handling.

And by the way: since this is apparently a hosted site you are using: 
there are *very* good reasons to disable that feature. It would be a massive security problem for a web space hoster.

Comment: But `phpinfo()` can be disabled via `.htacsess` by using `php_value disable_functions phpinfo`

Comment: @ErfanAzhdari And what is it you want to express with that statement? What does that have to do with the question or answer?

Comment: I wanted to see if phpinfo can be enabled by using the `php_value` in `.htaccess`.

Comment: @ErfanAzhdari While it is indeed possible to control (some) php configuration options this way you should also be aware of the limitations: this will only work when using php as an apache module, only one of the various flavors of usage, and that option has to be granted in an explicit manner. So if a hosting company disabled that function by purpose then you can be pretty sure that they did _not_ grant you the right to enable it again. Just as mentioned in the question: _for very good reasons_ ...