# enable "exec" function on run time in php

Tags: php

is it possible enable "exec" in php.

Here is my code :

```
$newstring = 'readfile,passthru,shell_exec,popen,telnet,friends';

ini_set('disable_functions', $newstring);
```

is it possible? or any other way to enable it, except php.ini. because I can't access php.ini in my server. I want to do it on run time only for this project.

I check other questions [Enable exec function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670847/enable-exec-function)  but I did not get any solution.

Comment: If that were possible, what would be the point of having `disable_functions`?

Comment: sometimes, server configurations allow to have a php.ini in your own home directory that will parse and provide only for your apache instance.

Comment: `but I did not get any solution` - seems more likely you read it wasn't possible and didn't like that answer. -1.

Comment: I get other result and they told that using .htaccess its possible. but when I tried to do its not happening. thats why I post this question to get proper solution. there was no reason to negative my question. because everyone post here to get better solution, I don't have so much time to waste to post a duplicate question.

Comment: `I get other result and they told that using .htaccess its possible` "other results" are not shown, but even so you link to an identical question, which has answers each of which says "no". The top answer links to the php documentation which [explicitly states it's not possible](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) (as linked below). To be a valid question you need to ask how to do whatever it is you're trying to exec - otherwise it's just a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

> disable_functions string
>   This directive allows you to disable certain
>   functions for security reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited list of
>   function names. disable_functions is not affected by Safe Mode.
>
> Only internal functions can be disabled using this directive.
>   User-defined functions are unaffected.
>
> **This directive must be set in php.ini** For example, you cannot set this
>   in httpd.conf.

[Source (PHP.net)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)

Answer (score 0):

If you could enable it without using `php.ini`, PHP essentially would have a security vulnerability. If it's within `disable_functions` in the php.ini, there's nothing you can do.

What you can do however is see if there is any function similar to `exec` that can enable you to accomplish the goal. `shell_exec`, `system`, etc.. that isn't disabled. If they're all disabled, though, you won't be able to enable them to reach this functionality.